# CloudPages, triggers a welcome journey successfully, but doesn't personalize the content based on the form submission?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I have a cloud page sign-up form and it is successfully adding users to the data extension, and the Welcome email triggers as well.  The problem is that the first name personalization doesn't display - the default does.

anyone know why this might be the case?

We write to the "Mailing Database" DE using Cloud Pages, which works, and then email that deploys after via a Journey is coded as:

```
%%[

SET @name = LookUp("Mailing Database", "first_name","email",EmailAddr)

IF @name == "" OR IsNull(@name) == "True" THEN

]%%

We didn't catch your name last time. Please <a href="http://www.site.com/name">click here</a> to tell us your name.

%%[ELSE]%%

Hi %%=ProperCase(@name)=%%!Not you? <a href="http://www.site.com/notyou">Update here</a>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Please share the code you are using in your CloudPage and email.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using SMART CAPTURE to subscribe members (and trigger the Journey as an Entry)

Answer (score 1):

That should work, I've tested your code and it's working for me, although I would simplify to:

```
%%[
    var @name, @greeting
    set @name = LookUp("Mailing Database", "first_name","email",EmailAddr)
    set @greeting = iif(empty(@name),
        'We didn&rsquo;t catch your name last time. Please <a href="#">click here</a> to tell us your name.',
        Concat('Hi ',ProperCase(@name),'! Not you? <a href="#">Update here</a>') )
]%%

%%=v(@greeting)=%%
```

Are you sure that the email address is in the Mailing Database DE? Try printing the email address in the email `%%=v(EmailAddr)=%%` to make sure.

Comment: I am... I have a feeling it's that I didn't create a new version of my Journey and the old mailing database was originally referenced in the html.  I'm going to check that shortly.